# Error: "No matching method getItem found taking 1 args for class com.amazonaws.services.dax.AmazonDaxClient"

Tags: clojure, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I'm facing an issue while working with the `com.amazonaws.services.dax.AmazonDaxClient` class in my Clojure code. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
No matching method getItem found taking 1 args for class com.amazonaws.services.dax.AmazonDaxClient
```

Here is my Clojure code snippet:

```clj
(ns problem
  (:import (com.amazonaws.client.builder AwsClientBuilder$EndpointConfiguration)
           (com.amazonaws.services.dax AmazonDaxClientBuilder)
           (com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model GetItemRequest)))

(let [dax-client-builder (-> (AmazonDaxClientBuilder/standard)
                             (.withEndpointConfiguration (AwsClientBuilder$EndpointConfiguration. "dax://some.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
                                                                                                  "eu-west-1")))
      dax-client         (.build dax-client-builder)]
  ; How can I convert dax-client to an AmazonDynamoDB instance?
  (.getItem dax-client
            (GetItemRequest.)))
```

I have successfully created an instance of `AmazonDaxClient` using `AmazonDaxClientBuilder`, but I need to convert it to an `AmazonDynamoDB` instance in order to use the `getItem` method that expect an `AmazonDynamoDB` object.

Any help or guidance on how to convert the `dax-client` instance to an `AmazonDynamoDB` instance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest making sure which version of the AWS SDK you're using, and make sure you're reading Javadocs that match.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [the docs for AmazonDaxClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dax/AmazonDaxClientBuilder.html), you will see that the type it builds is [AmazonDax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dax/AmazonDax.html). If you are sure that the type will be [AmazonDaxClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dax/AmazonDaxClient.html), and not one of the other implementations, you can provide a type hint:

```clj
(ns problem
  (:import (com.amazonaws.client.builder AwsClientBuilder$EndpointConfiguration)
           (com.amazonaws.services.dax AmazonDaxClient AmazonDaxClientBuilder)
           (com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model GetItemRequest)))

(let [dax-client-builder (-> (AmazonDaxClientBuilder/standard)
                             (.withEndpointConfiguration (AwsClientBuilder$EndpointConfiguration. "dax://some.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
                                                                                                  "eu-west-1")))
      dax-client         (.build dax-client-builder)]
  ; How can I convert dax-client to an AmazonDynamoDB instance?
  (.getItem ^AmazonDaxClient dax-client
            (GetItemRequest.)))
```

The type hint could be placed before the function call, if you will be calling more of the methods of the `AmazonDaxClient` object. You could of course test the type with [instance?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/instance_q), just to be sure.